# From a function, how to get details about the module which actually called this function?

Tags: node.js

In a general-purpose function, I would like to get informations about the module which *calls* this function (especially the base directory, which can itself be retrieved inside a module with `path.dirname(module.filename)`).

### What I tried

For now, the only way I found to do it is to add `module` as a parameter for the function:

**lib/my-lib.js**:

```
const path = require('path');

exports.print_calling_module_path = function(calling_module) {
    console.log(path.dirname(calling_module.filename));
}
```

**main.js**:

```
const my_lib = require('./lib/my-lib.js');

console.log('Here is the path of this actual module:');
my_lib.print_calling_module_path(module);
```

... but it forces to use an extra parameter, which pollutes the argument list of functions with a (possibly?) deductible information.

### What I'm looking for

For example:

**lib/my-lib.js**:

```
const path = require('path');

exports.print_calling_module_path = function(/* no extra argument */) {
    let calling_module = .... ;  // <== How to get this ??
    console.log(path.dirname(calling_module.filename));
}
```

**main.js**:

```
const my_lib = require('./lib/my-lib.js');

console.log('Here is the path of this actual module:');    
my_lib.print_calling_module_path(/* no extra argument */);
```

Inside the `print_calling_module_path()` function, how can I get the calling module object, without passing it as a parameter? Maybe something dealing with the stack trace?

Comment: Not an expert by any means, but the only time I've seen call stack info in JS is in an error - so you could do something like `new Error().stack` and then parse `new Error().stack.split(/\n\s+at /)`

Comment: No pretty lib or public code for this kind of stuff?

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer to find out how to do it? Google yields the `Function.caller` option as well. Unlike in smalltalk-influenced languages, there doesn't seem to be any built-in like Python's `inspect.currentframe` or whatever, so whatever ends up happening you'll probably have to do something hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use `new Error().stack` as a.p suggested; here the final code, following the example in the question:

#### lib/my-lib.js:

```
function unique_filter(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

function get_module_stack() {
    return new Error().stack.split(/\n/)
        .map(line => line.match(/\(([^:\)]*)/))  // Match lines with filenames
        .filter(match => match !== null)         // Remove null matches
        .map(match => match[1])                  // Map to the the actual filenames
        .filter(unique_filter)                   // Make filenames unique
}

exports.print_calling_module_path = function()
{
    console.log(get_module_stack()[1]);
}
```

However I'm not sure if this method is reliable enough to use it for production.
Any comment about it will be welcome.

Comment: It depends. Generally speaking it is not recommended in many languages including javascript. Getting stacktrace is very expensive and blocking operation. But on the other hand, in your particular use case it can be micro-optimisation (not worth bothering about it).

Answer (score 1):

Check out documentation https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_object
They mention `require.main` and `require.parent` properties. 
If it will not work for you, then use a.p's comment about using `new Error().stack`

Comment: Thanks for your response; will look about it a bit later